# How do I have VS Code run a bash script (or other script) when it opens?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I do most of my development via VS Code on my local machine. Whenever I open the editor I manually run a bash script (in the integrated terminal) that does the following things:

1. Starts a local instances of several webapp with hot-reload enabled
2. Starts the Dagster UI via Dagit
3. Starts the ML Flow UI
4. Starts a Tensorboard server
   etc...

I sometimes forget to run the bash script, which causes the occasional frustration when I have to re-run things or interrupt my work for this.

The most expedient way to fix it that comes to mind is to set things up so the .sh script runs whenever VS Code is opened.

Any ideas if this is possible? Maybe via an extension?

Comment: If you can get used to running vscode itself from the commandline, you can add a function to your bashrc which is like an alias for `code`, but also runs your extra functionality. Or write a script which does that and replace the vscode icon in your desktop with this script.

Comment: Would that work? I have a lot of environment variables and configs in VS Code, so not 100% sure running the script on the non-integrated terminal would work - but I'll try

Answer (score 1):

No extension needed, try to adapt following .vscode/tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0", 
    "presentation": { "echo": false },
    "tasks": [
        { "label": "First", "type": "shell", "command": "echo Run whatever scripts needed here; exec bash", "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" } }
    ]   
}
```

Comment: a command of type `shell` is, well, already _in_ a shell. Why have it spawn another shell as a child? (Similarly, you're telling the _child_ shell to `exec bash` at the end, but its parent is still there in memory running it).

Answer (score 1):

VS Code have tasks support, like Grunt/Gulp/etc, which include running arbitrary shell scripts. You can run pretty much anything you want and you can find out more in [the official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)